# How to insert this script into Entity Framework Core and SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I´m going through tutorial

[CRUD Operation using ASP.NET Core 2.2 and React Redux with Entity Framework Core (Database First Approach) and PrimeReact Components](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3132485/CRUD-Operation-using-ASP-NET-CORE-2-2-and-React-Re)

And I'm stuck at step 2 - Create the database and table.

I run the tutorial by having the sample solution project open in one VS window and at the same time I follow the tutorial step-by-step creating it from scratch into my own Visual Studio solution. But I can't see where to insert this Step 2 script into SQL Server.

> **2. Create the Database and Table** In this article, I am using Entity Framework Core using database first approach. To use this approach, we need to create one sample database table in SQL Server. Please run the following script in your SQL Server:

```
USE [master]
GO
/****** Object:  Database [ContactDB]    Script Date: 4/21/2019 4:11:09 PM ******/
CREATE DATABASE [ContactDB]
CONTAINMENT = NONE
ON PRIMARY
( NAME = N'Contact', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files _
  (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Contact.mdf' , _
  SIZE = 5120KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
LOG ON
( NAME = N'Contact_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files _
  (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Contact_log.ldf' , _
  SIZE = 1024KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
GO

ALTER DATABASE [ContactDB] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 110
GO

IF (1 = FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled'))
BEGIN
    EXEC [ContactDB].[dbo].[sp_fulltext_database] @action = 'enable'
END
GO

ALTER DATABASE [ContactDB] SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT OFF
GO

ALTER DATABASE [ContactDB] SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO

ALTER DATABASE [ContactDB] SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER DATABASE [ContactDB] SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
GO

ALTER DATABASE [ContactDB] SET ARITHABORT OFF
GO

ALTER DATABASE [ContactDB] SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF
GO

ALTER DATABASE [ContactDB] SET AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS ON
GO

ALTER DATABASE [ContactDB] SET AUTO_SHRINK OFF
GO

ALTER DATABASE [ContactDB] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS ON
GO

ALTER DATABASE [ContactDB] SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT OFF
GO

ALTER DATABASE [ContactDB] SET CURSOR_DEFAULT  GLOBAL
GO

ALTER DATABASE [ContactDB] SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF
GO

ALTER DATABASE [ContactDB] SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
GO

ALTER DATABASE [ContactDB] SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO

ALTER DATABASE [ContactDB] SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS OFF
GO

ALTER DATABASE [ContactDB] SET  DISABLE_BROKER
GO

ALTER DATABASE [ContactDB] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC OFF
GO

ALTER DATABASE [ContactDB] SET DATE_CORRELATION_OPTIMIZATION OFF
GO

ALTER DATABASE [ContactDB] SET TRUSTWORTHY OFF
GO

ALTER DATABASE [ContactDB] SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION OFF
GO

ALTER DATABASE [ContactDB] SET PARAMETERIZATION SIMPLE
GO

ALTER DATABASE [ContactDB] SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT OFF
GO

ALTER DATABASE [ContactDB] SET HONOR_BROKER_PRIORITY OFF
GO

ALTER DATABASE [ContactDB] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE
GO

ALTER DATABASE [ContactDB] SET  MULTI_USER
GO

ALTER DATABASE [ContactDB] SET PAGE_VERIFY CHECKSUM 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [ContactDB] SET DB_CHAINING OFF
GO

ALTER DATABASE [ContactDB] SET FILESTREAM( NON_TRANSACTED_ACCESS = OFF )
GO

ALTER DATABASE [ContactDB] SET TARGET_RECOVERY_TIME = 0 SECONDS
GO

USE [ContactDB]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Contacts]    Script Date: 4/21/2019 4:11:09 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Contacts]
(
    [ContactId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Phone] [nvarchar](50) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Contact] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ContactId] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, _
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

USE [master]
GO

ALTER DATABASE [ContactDB] SET READ_WRITE
GO
```

I went ahead and are now in the middle of Step 3, I feel I must have the above SQL script insert

Comment: You just need to run the given script from your SSMS

Comment: (SSMS = SQL Server Management Studio)

Comment: Thanks I read about that now, I get Directory lookup for the file "C:\Program Files(x86)\Micr... failed I guess I have to create the dir where the db will be

Comment: In the `CREATE DATABASE [ContactDB]` is it possible to have the db in the Visual Studio project  root, if so how can I get the path? In the script like this ` FILENAME = 'root-path'`

Comment: You can put the files wherever you want. Just edit the paths in the script.